# How to push same code in different repositories on github using gitbash

Tags: git, github

I have created repository xyz in github and push the code using

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:user/ci.git
```

then

```
git push -u origin master
```

Now code uploaded to ci directory successfully ,then I created another directory abc in github and used the command

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:user/abc.git
```

but got error

```
error: remote origin already exists.
```

I didn't understand why I can't make another copy to different repository in github

Comment: You can, you can't call both of them `origin` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but you must give another name to your remote, you can call it `abc` for example.

```sh
git remote add abc git@github.com:user/abc.git

# then
git push -u abc master
```

Comment: can u please tell me why origin should not use here

Comment: "origin" is not a special keyword, it's just a name. With `git remote add origin git@github.com:user/ci.git` you're adding one remote, called "origin", another one must be named differently.